# Como funciona o fluxo final do git-flow (release)?

Tags: git, git-flow

Resumidamente (considere o uso do git-flow): criei um repositório, gerei minha feature, criei uma release, finalizei essa release, consultei o log do branch develop e tive como output:

```
commit a6676da74f99342dd85e50e1251fd662d0be2680
Merge: 2c4958f 82190a0
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 11 19:13:37 2018 +0000

    Merge tag 'v1.0.0' into develop

    v1.0.0

commit 82190a041c9b3909a94fc74f47675fe0cae0d5de
Merge: f09850e 2c4958f
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 11 19:13:28 2018 +0000

    Merge branch 'release/v1.0.0'
```

Pelo que entendi o commit `82190a041c9b3909a94fc74f47675fe0cae0d5de` é o merge do branch release, já `a6676da74f99342dd85e50e1251fd662d0be2680` seria um merge do commit referenciado pela tag v1.0.0, este entendimento esta correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após realizar alguns testes consegui definir que é isso mesmo.

Quando um `git flow release finish <identificador da release>` é executado, algumas das ações disparadas são:

- Executar um `merge --no-ff release/<identificador da release>` no **master** e gerada uma *tag* com o `<identificador da release>`
- Na sequência um `merge --no-ff release/<identificador da release>` e `merge --no-ff <hash do commit referenciado pela tag>` é aplicado no **develop**...

Ao inspecionar o commit abaixo (commit mais recente do branch **develop** após release finish) consegui achar 2 hash (dffb709 e 9d6b578), sendo um para o commit referenciado pela tag no branch master e o outro para o commit mais recente em develop.

```
$ git show a6676da74f99342dd85e50e1251fd662d0be2680 commit 214157701f6cbe4f66d1802f9a93089d74aa45c6 (HEAD -> develop) Merge: dffb709 9d6b578 Author: Your Name <you@example.com> Date:   Wed Apr 11 18:36:39 2018 -0300

    Merge tag 'v1.0.0' into develop

    v1.0.0 primeira versão estavel
```